# How to get results of each step in cucumber hooks(After)

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am currently using cucumberjs version 6.0.5 and I cannot find the beforestep and afterstep hook to capture the step by step result of scenario.

I have tried to get it in After hook but it seems to show the overall result of scenario not steps.

Answer (score 0):

https://v6.webdriver.io/docs/options.html

https://webdriver.io/docs/options

Documentation of configuration file . If you check the available property there is a hook called afterStep which you can use :

> afterStep# Runs after a Cucumber Step.
>
> Parameters:
>
> step (Pickle.IPickleStep): Cucumber step object scenario (IPickle):
> Cucumber scenario object result: (object): results object containing
> step results result.passed (boolean): true if scenario has passed
> result.error (string): error stack if scenario failed result.duration
> (number): duration of scenario in milliseconds